# How can I deal with content uri in ndk?

Tags: android, android-ndk, uri

I'm working on an android application that need send a file to NDK and  do some processes on that file.The problem is, after picking a file, Android (due to permissions) returns a content Uri while NDK needs a real (absolute) path of this file.

Now, the question is "How can I deal with this problem between NDK and Android java (or kotlin) source code?"

There is some codes to convert content uri to real filepath but they didn't work and returned empty string. also, I know how to work on a content uri in java(kotlin) side.

in kotlin:

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_FILE_TXT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            data?.let {
                doProcess(it.data.toString())  // data is Uri and this method is native method
            }
        }
    }
```

in cpp:

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_org_my_apps_cpptest_MainActivity_doProcess(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */,
        jstring file) {
    //content uri not working, needs a real path
    std::string rfn = env->GetStringUTFChars(file, nullptr);
    std::ifstream is(rfn, std::ios::in);
    if(is.is_open()){
        // processing ...
        is.close();
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: "There is some codes to convert content uri to real filepath but they didn't work and returned empty string" -- a `Uri` does not have to point to a file on the filesystem, let alone a file that you can access. "How can I deal with this problem between NDK and Android java (or kotlin) source code?" -- use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` for the content identified by your `Uri`. Copy the bytes of the content to a `File` that you control. Then, use that file from the NDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for replying. "a Uri does not have to point to a file on the filesystem, let alone a file that you can access." I know and for this reason I asked the question. the file copy solution also is good only for simple and small files not for large files like movies, compressed files, ... .

Comment: "the file copy solution also is good only for simple and small files" -- again, a `Uri` does not have to point to a file on the filesystem. It might point to a file in the cloud, such as from Google Drive, and such things can include "movies, compressed files". If you only want to deal with files on the filesystem, do not use an `Intent` to bring up a content picker. Instead, have users copy files into your app's portion of external storage (`getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`), and then you can work directly with that file on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Although a `Uri` doesn't need to be a file, in some situations we can be sure it is. Think of a file queried on the MediaStore for example. In that case, you can use methods from ContentResolver like `openFileDescriptor`, `openAssetFileDescriptor`, `openTypedAssetFileDescriptor`. Those return object like the `AssetFileDescriptor` or `ParcelFileDescriptor`. From the returned object you can get the file descriptor of the opened file and pass that on the NDK level. For example on `ParcelFileDescriptor` you have `getFd()` or `detachFd()` depending if you want to give ownership. This works with Scoped Storage on Android 10.